# React native expo app crashing after splash screen even it's perfectly on expo go development mode

Tags: expo, splash-screen, mobile-application, expo-go, expo-splash-screen

I've wasted my 2 days in this problem, Actually I created an expo app and it's running completely fine in expo go app but when I make build (apk) using the command

```
npx eas build -p android --profile preview
```

and install in my phone. It opens but closes automatically after displaying splash screen. I've tried multiple time so please help.
Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "new_breakawaydelivery_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-av": "~13.2.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "firebase": "^10.0.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^2.0.7",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.1.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.9.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I want to get an working apk build of this app. Any help would be appreciated.